# Can't drag ionRangeSlider slider while updating

Tags: javascript, slider, range

I am using ionRangeSlider to create a media player, I bind it with the track playing so whenever the track is playing the slider is updating automatically, but the problem is when I want to drag the slider it can't get dragged and if I stop the track and with that the updating I can drag the slider.

I am new to javascript and I want to create this player for a client.

Anything would help and thank you in advance.

Here is the code that initialize the ionRangeSlider:

```
trackSlider = $("#trackRange");
    trackSlider.ionRangeSlider({
        skin: "big",
        min: 0,
        hide_min_max: true,
        hide_from_to: true,
        step: 1,
        onStart: function (data) {

        },
        onChange: function (data) {
            //If there is a track playing
            if(!player.notPlaying()){

                player.setCurrentTime(data.from);
                var width = $(".irs-bar.irs-bar--single").width();
                $(".middle .progress").css({"width": width + "px"});    
            }else{

            }
        },
        onFinish: function (data) {

        },
        onUpdate: function (data) {         }   
    });
```

And Here is the code that update the slider

```
$(audio).on('timeupdate', function(){
        let data = trackSlider.data("ionRangeSlider");
        data.update({
            from: player.currentTime
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example ?

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... here is the code.